# Paginate using with_exclusive_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Is there a way in which we can paginate using with_exclusive_scope in Rails 2.3?

```
@albums = Album.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 12, :conditions => cond)
```

works fine.

```
Album.with_exclusive_scope {find(:all, :conditions => cond)}
```

works fine.

Can we combine with_exclusive_scope and paginate?

Answer (score 0):

@albums = Album.find_allx(opts).paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 12)

with_exclusive_scope is a protected method, so it has to be called from a class message. In this case the class method is find_allx()